# Laravel: Database [default] not configured when using an Eloquent model, but works on Facade

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model that extends Laravel's Eloquent model.  When I attempt to use it, I get the error `Database [default] not configured`.  However, when I simply call the `DB` facade, it works just fine.  Code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Owners extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $connection = 'default';

    public function records()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OwnersToRecords::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

    public function zones()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OwnersToZones::class, 'record_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When invoking by using `$owner = new Owners`, I get the error.  When invoking by `DB::table('owners')`, the table works fine.  So, what's wrong?

Comment: Please include your config/database.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what's wrong?

This line is wrong, because there is no db connection with this name in your `config/database.php` file.

```sql
protected $connection = 'default';
```

Either remove it completely, in which case a default connection would be used, or specify a correct database connection name from your config file.

Note: Unless you have a very specific requirements i.e. working with multiple db's or absolutely need a separate independent connection for a model etc. **you don't want** to explicitly specify connection name in your model.